# Checking wheter a data element doesn't contain a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do this by using jQuery and using it's `*=` feature. I don't really see what I'm doing wrong, I used the following code,

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div data-name="hello29">
    29
  </div>

  <div data-name="bye23">
    23
  </div>

  <div data-name="hello96">
    96
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery/JS**

```
$('.wrapper').find('div:not([data-name*="hello"])').hide();
```

**JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/tgtesuq4/

I would further explain about my issue but it seems so simple but doesn't work..

Comment: [Seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/t5c09use/), you've forgotten to add jQuery to your fiddle.

Comment: @Teemu *facepalms*

Comment: Yes.Updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tgtesuq4/3/

Comment: The second fiddle states ´data-name="hello"´ once * is added the it seems to work fine hidding ´data-name="bye23"´. What's the problem?